# How to run a script at login/logout in OS X?

Tags: macos, login, logout

I'm toying around with building a custom render farm manager, and I want to automatically add OS X machines to the render farm when they are not in use.

Is there a way to trigger a script to run once any user has logged out then stop when any user has logged in?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are [several ways to run scripts at login/logout in OS X](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CustomLogin.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW10-SW1), some are more recent and only apply to 10.5 and above, some are rather deprecated, but the fastest one would be to add a `Login Hook`.

First, create the script you want to run. Open up a Terminal and enter:

```
touch ~/script.sh
open -e !$
```

This will open a text editor. Enter the script, e.g. with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
# insert your script here
```

Save the file. In your terminal, run:

```
chmod +x ~/script.sh
```

This will make the file executable. Now, let's add it as a hook:

```
sudo defaults write com.apple.loginwindow LoginHook /usr/local/bin/script.sh
```

There's also the `Logout Hook` counterpart:

```
sudo defaults write com.apple.loginwindow LogoutHook /usr/local/bin/script2.sh
```

I've tested this on OS X 10.6, and it *should* work even up to 10.8. Keep in mind that the script runs as `root` and there is only one hook for login and logout respectively.

To undo all that, enter

```
sudo defaults delete com.apple.loginwindow LoginHook
sudo defaults delete com.apple.loginwindow LogoutHook
```

Note that this method is not recommended for deployment or anything, but if you're only using it like your question stated, that should be no problem.

Comment: doesn't work for yosemite

Comment: Login and logout scripts are a deprecated technology. In most cases, you should use launchd jobs instead, as described here: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW7-BCIEDDBJ


Source:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CustomLogin.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW10-SW1

Answer (score 8):

Login hooks were deprecated in 10.4 in favor of launchd. To run a script at login, save a plist like this as `~/Library/LaunchAgents/test.plist`. It's loaded on the next login even if you don't run `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/test.plist`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN
http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>test</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>say</string>
        <string>test</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

For more information, see `man launchd.plist` and [this blog post](http://nb.nathanamy.org/2012/07/schedule-jobs-using-launchd/).

Comment: According to the linked blog post, this will load the plist the first time you log in, and keep it loaded until the system restarts.  How do you use launchd to run a script at every login?  Or at logout?

Comment: This solution worked for me on every login. 
macOS Monterey v12.3

Answer (score 0):

[The preferred route is using apple's `launchd`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CustomLogin.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW10-SW1).

- `launchd` `.plist` files can have, among others, one of the following keys:

  ```bash
  #: man launchd.plist

  RunAtLoad <boolean>
      This optional key is used to control whether your job is launched once 
      at the time the job is loaded. The default is false. This key should be 
      avoided, as speculative job launches have an adverse effect on system-
      boot and user-login scenarios.

  LaunchOnlyOnce <boolean>
      This optional key specifies whether the job can only be run once and 
      only once.  In other words, if the job cannot be safely respawned 
      without a full machine reboot, then set this key to be true.

  StartOnMount <boolean>
      This optional key causes the job to be started every time a filesystem 
      is mounted.
  ```
- upon login, `launchd` will scan through `FILES` and load the daemons and agents defined therein (via `.plist` files).

  ```
  #: man 8 launchd
  FILES
          ~/Library/LaunchAgents         Per-user agents provided by the user.
          /Library/LaunchAgents          Per-user agents provided by the administrator.
          /Library/LaunchDaemons         System-wide daemons provided by the administrator.
          /System/Library/LaunchAgents   Per-user agents provided by Apple.
          /System/Library/LaunchDaemons  System-wide daemons provided by Apple.
  ```

therefore:

- regarding running a script at login:

  1. create a daemon or agent specification/definition (`.plist`) file
  2. use `RunAtLoad` `.plist` key, maybe also use `LaunchOnlyOnce`

  > - if instead you want to run specifically when a certain disk-image/volume/filesystem is mounted, you can use `StartOnMount`

  1. place the `.plist` file in one of the appropriate `FILES` directories

  Now `launchd` will automatically load it up upon login and run it according to your specification/definition.
- regarding running a script at logout: you could try running logout stuff upon login, but other than that I don't know of a key that has the functionality of triggering a daemon/agent upon logout, however you could try to find an event that happens upon logout, that `launchd` can detect, and use that as trigger for your daemon/agent spec./definition.

  > - `launchd.plist` has a key called `Sockets`, maybe there's a way to do it with that

Answer (score -1):

For these hooks to work in 10.10 you will need to do this:

1. Open the `/etc/ttys` file: In the Finder, choose Go to Folder from the Go menu, type `/etc/`, then click Go.
2. In the resulting window, open the `ttys` file in your preferred text editor (such as TextEdit).
3. Look for a line that reads:

   `console "/System/Library/CoreServices/loginwindow.app/Contents/MacOS/loginwindow" vt100 on secure window=/System/Library/CoreServices/WindowServer onoption="/usr/libexec/getty std.9600"`
4. Edit this line so that it reads as follows (there are no breaks in this line):

   `console "/System/Library/CoreServices/loginwindow.app/Contents/MacOS/loginwindow -LoginHook /path/to/script" vt100 on secure window=/System/Library/CoreServices/WindowServer onoption="/usr/libexec/getty std.9600"`

   i.e., add `-LoginHook /path/to/script` (where *`/path/to/script`* is the full path to the script that you want to execute when a user logs in) just before the second quote (`"`) mark.
5. Save the file.

Be sure that the text editor you use to edit this file does not break the line above into more than one line.

---

or follow full instruction here:

http://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT2420

Comment: doesn't work for yosemite