# How can I execute a script each time I log in and out from OS X?

Tags: macos, bash, osx-lion, script, login

What I want is to send a URL with variables to a server which will track when someone is present based on when they login and logout of their workstation.

I've tried setting the `LoginHook` in `com.apple.loginwindow` to "/Users/Username/Desktop/script.sh". `script.sh` works when I execute it myself from the terminal, but it doesn't run from the `LoginHook`.

The script executes the following, where `$USER` should be the name of the user currently logged in:

```
curl -kd "author=$USER&type=inout&message=in" https://some.server.com/timetrack
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't use `$USER` here. Do you know if the script executes at all?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking the same, but even a simple touch script won't work... Is there another way I can check if the script is executing?

Comment: And if I can't use $USER here, because the script should be executed as root, then how can I execute a script at login/logout which sends the current user's name to a server?

Comment: I rephrased your question to state what you want to achieve, hope this makes sense. Not on a Mac right now, so I can't test. In theory the login/logout hook should work, see: [How to run a script at login/logout in OS X?](http://superuser.com/questions/295924/how-to-run-a-script-at-login-logout-in-os-x) Have you tried setting `#!/bin/bash` at the start of your script? It appears you can get the username in the script with `$1` instead of `$USER`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. How do you guys mark stuff as code in questions and in comments? I always forget this.

Comment: In comments only with backticks, `\`like this\`` – and in questions with backticks or by indenting it with 4 spaces or pressing `Ctrl-K`.

Comment: *slhck*'s comment points definitely in the right direction: Add the line `#!/bin/bash` to the beginning of the script, copy the script to `/usr/local/bin/` (better than somewhere in their homedir because users could delete it and create a modified version of it in its place) and configure LoginHook to point to it. If `$USER` still doesn't work replace it with `$(/usr/bin/whoami)`.

Comment: `$(/usr/bin/whoami)` returns `Root` because that is the user executing the script. Any idea how I can get the name of the user I'm logging in/out with?

Comment: Testing with this script: `echo $USER > /Users/Me/Desktop/iam.txt` works on logout, however on login the file is created but empty. Ideas?

Comment: And if you run the script in `~/.bash_login` and `~/.bash_logout`? The user is logged in and `$USER ` or `$(/usr/bin/whoami)` should give you the right user.

Comment: *slhck* got it right again, use `$1` to get the short name of the user who is logging in when using LoginHook (see http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CustomLogin.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW10-SW1)

Comment: Thank you guys very much for helping me successfully accomplish exactly what I wanted. By the way, .bash_login doesn't seem to do anything in Lion, and .bash_logout executes only when you exit the shell in Terminal. Can one of you post an answer so I can mark this question as answered?

Comment: @slhck: You've done all the original research so it's fair that you post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `LoginHook` and `LogoutHook` as described in [How to run a script at login/logout in OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/295924/how-to-run-a-script-at-login-logout-in-os-x) would probably be the easiest approach. It's considered deprecated but works until 10.8 and might even work beyond that.

Make sure your script has a correct [hashbang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashbang) so the launching process will know how to execute it. After all your script could be anything from Ruby to Python or simply Bash.

So, for example:

```
sudo defaults write com.apple.loginwindow LoginHook /usr/local/bin/curl.sh
```

And `/usr/local/bin/curl.sh` being:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -kd "author=${1}&type=inout&message=in" https://some.server.com/timetrack
```

To access the user who is logging in, you need to use `$1` instead of `$USER` because the latter is a variable that only exists in an actual shell environment, which doesn't exist if you use login scripts.

Comment: Excellent answer. I'm sure it'll help someone in the future. Out of curiosity, if `LoginHook` is considered deprecated what would be the more current way of doing this?

Comment: You'd need to create a `launchd` job – however it'd require you to write an XML `.plist` file that describes the job and then load it. Using Login Hooks is just much easier, but of course the drawbacks are that you can only use one at a time.