# Setting up a terminal command to execute on restart (Mac OS X 10.8.2)

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, boot, scheduled-tasks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run a script at login/logout in OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/295924/how-to-run-a-script-at-login-logout-in-os-x)

I have some external USB 2.0 hard drives and they obnoxiously spin down every minute or so. Then when I go to do something on my Mac, I have to wait for the drives to spin up and it delays my workflow quite a bit. I have been researching these problems for several months now with no easy answers. My Google-foo finally found a Terminal command as such:

```
sudo pmset -a spindown 0
```

This seems to work and my drives no longer spin down. However, I'd like to be able to somehow execute this command automatically if I ever restart my computer. Is there a way to do that? I'm on Mac OS X 10.8.2 Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copied from here: [Running script upon login mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442364/running-script-upon-login-mac/6445525#6445525)

> - Start Automator.app
> - Select "Application"
> - click "Show library" in the toolbar (if hidden)
> - Add "Run shell script" (from the Actions/Utilities)
> - Copy & paste your script into the window
> - Test it
> - Save somewhere, for example you can make an "Applications" folder in your HOME (you will get a `your_name.app`)
> - Go to System Preferences -> Accounts -> Login items
> - Add this app