# Mac OS X login script for specific user

Tags: macos, mac, bash, login, bash-scripting

I need to be able to run a bash script every time a specific user logs in.
The solution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/295924/how-to-run-a-script-at-login-logout-in-os-x) is for all users.

Is there any way to specify the user, and if not is there a way for the bash script to check the username that has logged in?

Answer (score 1):

If you go with the [LaunchAgent solution](https://superuser.com/questions/295924/how-to-run-a-script-at-login-logout-in-os-x#519571), just put it in that user's ~/Library/LaunchAgents folder, and it'll only run when that particular user logs in.

If you go with the [LoginHook solution](https://superuser.com/questions/295924/how-to-run-a-script-at-login-logout-in-os-x#296136), you need to write the script so that it checks the username (passed to the script as $1):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" = "fred" ]; then
    # do stuff that only applies to fred
fi
```